# Arduino splitting received string in words

Tags: arduino, strtok, scanf

I have the following problem:

I want to receive from the serial port  data in the following form:
"30,45,33,22\n";
I want to split the string by the commas after entering the '\n'char and put each value in an int array.The problem is i tried a combination of **strtok** and **sscanf** and it just won't work:

```
  #define PARAM_NR 10
    Timer tt;
    int i=0;
    int index=0;
    bool stringComplete=false;
    char recString[MAX_LEN];
    char buf[20];

int commands[PARAM_NR];




void serialEv()
    {
      char aux;
      char *token;
      int i=0;

      while(Serial.available())
      {
        aux=Serial.read();
        if(i!='\n' )
        {
        recString[i++]=aux;
        recString[i]='\0';

        }
        if(aux=='\n');
        {

         token=strtok(recString,",");
         while(token!=NULL)
         {
         token=strtok(NULL,",");
          sscanf(token,"%d",&commands[index]); 
         Serial.println(commands[index]);
         index++;
         if(index==PARAM_NR)
         index=0;
         break;
         }
        }


      }
    }
```

Example:

Input:

```
1,1,1
```

Output:

```
1
0
0
```

It seems it prints only 1 on the first position and 0 on the others.
If i try another input

ex:
input 1:

```
1,1,1
```

input 2

```
3,4,5
```

output:

```
 1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

Comment: `i!='\n'` this doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after i swapped the these 2 instructions :

```
 sscanf(token,"%d",&commands[index]); 
   token=strtok(NULL,",");
```

I still don't get how strtok works.

Comment: PS Update:It seems it doesnt work since if i am using Serial.println(command[index]); it will print all digits on separate rows.What is wrong here?